# PHP DateTime class not working

Tags: php, drupal

I am wondering if there is any reason why the DateTime class would not be working or supported by my server. My specs are:

1. PHP 5.3.10
2. Drupal 7.12

I'm not sure if it is a Drupal thing or what. I have no idea where to look if there was an error and it bugs me that something that is supposed to be part of the core isn't. A simple script like:

```
<?php
    $d = new DateTime();
    echo $d->format("Y-m-d");
?>
```

works on my local MAMP test server but not on the remote server. So is it some sort of Drupal shenanigans or something that might have been turned off/excluded in PHP? How can I fix it?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Ah ok I thought I wasn't getting any errors in my error_log but it turns out I am. They give an uncaught Exception error: "It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings." So I guess that means I have to explicitly set the timezone?

Comment: Yes. You do this either in your php.ini file or in your php script using `date_default_tiemzone_set()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: Ah ha! The default timezone isn't set in the php.ini file. Weird I could of sworn it was working a few builds ago. I did recently update PHP. Does that get reset when I update? Also, to set it do I just put something like "UTC" as the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.installation.php:

> There is no installation needed to use these functions; they are part of the PHP core.

There are some php.ini settings which could *potentially* have an affect on the DateTime operation, but I'm not sure if they would make it not work at all: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php

In light of the recent comment, you can set the TimeZone in your php.ini with the setting in the previous link, or you can do it at runtime with the `date_default_timezone_set()` function which accepts a timezone identifier that can be found in [this list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

More on the function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: @Matt That was the dilemma with the information I wanted to provide. In my defense, the question leaves much to be desired as well.

Comment: Well the problem left a lot be desired. I'm still a beginner in Web Dev and quickly finding out that debugging errors can be a little convoluted if you don't know what to do or where to look.